# Typescript Output File '../types.ts' Has Not Been Built from Source File '../types.d.ts' ts(6305)

Tags: typescript

I'm new to Typescript and currently trying to build a Vue Apps with Typescript. I wanted to make an `interface` that could be accessed globaly to any components, so I made a file called `~/utils/types.ts`

```js
// types.ts
export interface Url {
  name: string
  params?: Object
  query?: Object
}

export interface Links {
  text: string
  url: Url
}
```

When I tried to import it on my component, it gave me warning like below
[image: warning message]

It actually works, but it shows that warning in VScode. What should I do to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, my `tsconfig.json` file included this references property formatted like so:

```
"references": [
  {
    "path": "./tsconfig.vite-config.json"
  },
  {
    "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
  },
  {
    "path": "./tsconfig.vitest.json"
  }
]
```

All I did was remove the last two "path" properties, making my entire `tsconfig.json` file looking like this:

```
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.web.json",
  "include": ["env.d.ts", "src/**/*", "src/**/*.vue"],
  
  "compilerOptions": 
  {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": 
    {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },

"references": [
  {
    "path": "./tsconfig.vite-config.json"
  }
]
```

}

I don't fully understand why/how those path properties were causing the issue, but that's what did it for me. Hopefully this will help someone else!

Comment: I'll try it later

Comment: This worked, but any idea what are the ramifications of not having "path": "./tsconfig.app.json" referenced?

Comment: I think you can keep the tsconfig.app.json (if the file is there).  The problem for me was the configuration of the tsconfig.vitest.json
It needed an include e.g.

  "include": ["packages", "vitest.setup.ts", "typings/env.d.ts"],
Full example here
https://github.com/element-plus/element-plus/blob/dev/tsconfig.vitest.json